# Is it normal that "airmon-ng start wlan0" stops wifi on Kali?

Tags: kali-linux, airmon-ng

I am learning Kali Linux with web tutorials. I was starting with penetrating my Samsung's Hotspot WiFi. As shown on the tutorial I ran the command `airmon-ng start wlan0` but it caused the Wifi symbol on the bar to disappear and my internet connection was gone.

Is it normal or is there a problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using wlan0 as your monitoring device you give the process/service over to airmon-ng. This is normal you would normally use 2 Interfaces if you wanted to keep an internet connection while scanning the airwaves and hacking.

Im surprised that it let you do this while the wireless was active, normally it would throw me an error. So yes this is normal!

Comment: Do you know how can I restart the WiFi connection?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? service network-manager restart ?

Comment: Old question, but, just in case other people check stackexchange before they read the manpage; restarting the wifi connection is done by reversing the previous command.

List the interfaces with the 'airmon-ng' command, then follow that up with 'airmon-ng stop [full name of specific interface shown by airmon-ng command]'.